Is "think on your feet" used with positive or negative meanings?
I checked 2  chatbots and one says "think on your feet" is used in positive sentences and the other says it is used in negative ones.
The dictionary just says "think on your feet: to make a quick decision or give an answer quickly"
For example, "In the interview, they asked me a strange question and I nailed it by thinking on my feet" (positive)
"In the interview, they asked me a strange question and I got a wrong answer because I thought on my feet" (negative)

I don't see how thinking on one's feet can be seen as negative even in the OP's second example.   If you need to give an answer in an interview, you just have to do it, and the only way is to think on your feet.
Collins Dictionary explains this idiom:

to make good decisions and achieve things without having to think about them or plan them first [emphasis added]


Being a parent means thinking on your feet and adapting as you go along.

The example sentences from Times, Sunday Times further show the meanings as positive; I quote one here:

There's nothing wrong with learning to think on your feet; we could all use that particular skill at some point or another.
Times, Sunday Times (2017)

